# Getting error in Visual Studio in bin Bin folder "appxrecipe" is missing or malformed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I had created a new Maui project and ran the project on windows. It's giving me an error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP1600: The list of content files in the recipe file "xxxx.appxrecipe" is missing or malformed.
```

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview 17.2.0 Preview 3.0

I deleted the Bin and obj folders and clean the solution and ran it again this not working either. I repaired the Visual studio and ran it again. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Hi, I get the same error. Can you see the follow link, is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321652/in-winui3-c-sharp-app-vs2022-17-3-i-get-a-strange-error-when-i-start-the-app-h

Answer (score 1):

Though an old question, perhaps an answer will still be relevant to others.

I had this issue from developing a MAUI app of which I wanted to use without the `MsixPackage`. I just wanted to be able to launch the `exe` directly from directory without installing. So I did the needed configurations in the `csproj` file but forgot to update the `launchSettings.json` file found in Properties. I modified that and changed the `CommandName` from `MsixProject` to `Project` and voila!

This makes sense because if you are using `MsixPackage` then the `build.appxrecipe` will be needed to build the installer.

Hope this helps the next person.

Comment: Thank You!!  I could not get many of the WindowAppSDK-Samples to run, and this solved the problem!